# How to reshape 3D derivatives matrices to 3x3xn matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have 3D derivatives of image Dxx,Dyx,Dyy,Dxz,Dzz,Dzy each of 513x512x200
where 512x512 are the images dimensions of 200 images.
Now i want to use [`eig3`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27680-multiple-eigen-values-for-2x2-and-3x3-matrices/content/Eig3Folder/eig3.m) that can take 3x3xn matrix
How can i reshape these matrices to a 3x3xn matrix ?

**EDIT**

n is supposed to be the number of voxels and the 3x3 matrix should be like

Dxx Dxy Dxz

Dyx Dyy Dyz

Daz Dzy Dzz

Comment: So, input is a set of 200 images, each of 512x512 dimensions? Since 512 isn't divisible by 3, I am assuming you want to use upto 510 along
the height and width? Let's suppose you have 510x510 sized images and your voxel is 3x3, so it means we would have
170x170 voxels in each image? Each voxel would have eig3 3x1 vectors, thus we would have 170X170x3 eig3 vectors. So, how would
you like to store them? Please try to explain as much as you can. We can't help unless you try to explain it in a better way.

Comment: I basically want to form the hassian matrix of each voxel 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix
so i calculated the dxx,dxy,,etc of the images to form the hessian matrix but i got each derivative separately (i.e. Dxx is 512x512xnumber of images)
inorder to use the eig i mentioned it takes 3x3xn so n would be the number of voxels and 3x3 is the Hessian matrix of this voxel

Comment: so i was asking how to prepare the input matrix to the eig function

Comment: sorry again if it wasn't clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manipulation of the matrices can be achieved by using 'permute' and 'reshape' as follows.

```
 % say you saved your 2nd derivative 3D image as 'Ds'
 Ds = [Dxx(:) Dxy(:) Dxz(:) Dyz(:) Dyy(:) Dyz(:) Dzz(:) Dzy(:) Dzz(:)];


 % permute
 Ds = permute(Ds,[2 1]);

 % reshape
 n = numel(Dxx);
 Ds = reshape(Ds,[3 3 n]);
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you teng but how can i format the Ds matrix ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you were looking for something like this -

```
%%// M and N are the dims of each image and P is the count of images. 
%%// Please not that for 3x3 block processing, you would need to make sure that 
%%// the width of images are divisble by 3; if they are not, consider cropping or padding.
IN = some_MxNxP_data;

%%// In-code cropping, as mentioned earlier
IN = IN(:,1:3*floor(size(IN,2)/3),:);

%%// Final output would be a complex matrix of size Mx(N/3)xP
OUT = zeros(size(IN,1),size(IN,2)/3);

%%// Main calculation part that uses block processing creating 3x3 blocks and using eig3 on each of them 
for k = 1:size(IN,3)
    fun1 = @(block_struct) eig3(block_struct.data);
    OUT(:,:,k) = blockproc(double(IN(:,:,k)),[3 3],fun1);
end
```

**Edit 1**

**Code**

```
M = 7; %%// Image height, which must be replaced by actual data, 512 in your case
N = 7; %%// Image width, which must be replaced by actual data, 512 in your case
P = 5; %%// Number of images, which must be replaced by actual data, 200 in your case

%%// Your Dxx,Dyx... data, which is created randomly here, for demo
Dxx= rand(M,N,P);
Dyx= rand(M,N,P);
Daz= rand(M,N,P);
Dxy= rand(M,N,P);
Dyy= rand(M,N,P);
Dzy= rand(M,N,P);
Dxz= rand(M,N,P);
Dyz= rand(M,N,P);
Dzz= rand(M,N,P);

voxel_mat = zeros(3,3,M,N,P);
eig_mat = zeros(M,N,3);

for k0 = 1:P
    for k1 = 1:M
        for k2 = 1:N

            voxel_mat(:,:,k1,k2,k0) = [Dxx(k1,k2,k0) Dxy(k1,k2,k0) Dxz(k1,k2,k0); ...
                Dyx(k1,k2,k0) Dyy(k1,k2,k0) Dyz(k1,k2,k0); ...
                Daz(k1,k2,k0) Dzy(k1,k2,k0) Dzz(k1,k2,k0)];

            eig_mat(k1,k2,:,k0) = eig3(voxel_mat(:,:,k1,k2,k0));

        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much Divakar i think it will work but how should i collect them in one matrix to get the 3x3 matrix form for each voxel ?

Comment: Each 3x3 matrix would have created 3x1 eigen vector. That's why `OUT` would have a size of Mx(N/3)xP. How exactly do you want your output to be? What must be the `size` of your output? Please explain in little more detail maybe?

Comment: how can i collect the derivatives into IN matrix :) ? sorry but i'm kinda new to MATLAB

Comment: See Edit-1. Used loops here to play it safe. Hope this gets you closer to your goal!